# SQL Server find column difference from different tables and fill intermediate dates

Tags: sql-server, union, cumulative-sum

I have the purchase entry in one table `#temp1` and sales history in another table `#temp2` for multiple stores. There might be no sales, no purchase, or both/either of them in a day. I need to build a graph of daily stock.

Basically, I am stuck in the query part. For first part I need to combine both tables to view the data together...

[image]

Secondly, I need to find the cumulative values for the stock ; something like ...

[image]

After I get I need to plot it finally... help out !!! QUERY MASTER !!!

Comment: did you think of JOIN,UNION and WITH;

Answer (score 1):

If you start out by using a Union something like:

```
SELECT Store, Date, Purchase, 0 Sales FROM #temp1
UNION ALL
SELECT Store, Date, 0, Sales FROM #temp2
```

You have all the data in one table/view.  From there, you can get things consolidated by

```
 SELECT 
     Store, Date, 
     Sum(Purchase) Purchase, 
     Sum(Sales) Sales, 
     Sum(Purchase) - Sum(Sales) InStock  
GROUP BY
     Store, Date
```

That will give you a view with the Store, Date, Purchases, Sales and In Stock in one row.  If you work things via query rather than temp tables, you can easily use the final view to feed SSRS and draw your graph.

Hope that helps.

Comment: how to add the result of two table union into one table... i tried it creating new temp table ; which works in sql server but gives error in sql editor in ssrs reporting as 'table' keyword is not allowed...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the hint by @mark worked...

```
select store,date,ISNULL(purchase,0) as purchase,0 as sales 
into #tbl
from temp1
union all
select store,date,0 as purchase,ISNULL(sales,0) as sales from temp2

select store,sum(purchase) as PUR,sum(sales) as SAL,sum(purchase-sales) as STOCK from #tbl
group by store,date
order by storename

drop table #tbl
```

And, the empty dates in between are automatically managed by the SSRS reporting tool.
But, the cumulative sums are not able to solve till now...